# Do not want version number on my jar/ear/war while using maven to deploy to nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have an ant build invoked my jenkins that creates my .ear/.war file but using maven in jenkins to upload archive to Nexus for deployment tool to use.

The archive from ant is titled myear.ear but ends up as myear-version.ear in nexus upon deploy.

I do not want the version number added to the artifact - Any way to avoid this behavior?

Thank You!

Comment: Just curious, but why would you not want the version on your artefact?  Second, why are you using both ANT and Maven?  You should probably move to all Maven, your life will be easier :)

Comment: If you are using a repository manager the version is part of the definition how artifacts are stored in the Maven repository. If you don't like the version number don't use a repository manager like Nexus.

Answer (score 3):

The artifact in the Maven repository will always contain the version number as part of the filename since that is part of the Maven repository format. The filename is artifactId-version[-classifier].packaging.

However that is never really a problem because nothing stops you from downloading it following that naming convention and then changing the name of the downloaded file. And if you dont know the version you can query Nexus for the available versions via the REST API.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the finalName configuration inside your pom as below

```
    <build>
    <finalName>desiredName</finalName>
    </build>
```

Comment: This does NOT affect the name in the repo.